# Initializing an array of char

Tags: c++

I just wanna inquire as to whether the beneath code was ever endorsed by C++ in **ANY OF ITS VERSION**.

Since my instructor disclosed to me that this works, however when I attempted, I got compiler error.

```
char name[20];
name = "some random name";
```

I'm aware of different approaches to initialize name variable however simply let me know whether this work or not.

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: Arrays are not assignable in C or C++ - your instructor is wrong.

Comment: That's not how arrays work. You are treating `name` like a string

Comment: You can initialize name in one line ```char name[20] = "some random name";``` but can't set once it has been defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.**

If your instructor really said that, they are wrong.

Neither C nor C++ has ever permitted assignment of a string literal to an extant array of any type.

You can however *initialise* an array of `char` from such a literal:

```
char name[20] = "some arbitrary name";
```

… but you weren't doing initialisation; you were doing *assignment*. (Some older texts use "initialise" to mean "assign for the first time", for historical reasons; that's not accurate in C++.)

In C++ we instead tend to use, at the cost of some dynamic allocation, `std::string`, which does permit assignment:

```
std::string name;
name = "some arbitrary name";
name = "and now another one";
```

This was introduced *because* of the limitations of treating arrays like strings.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.
But our school doesn't allow to use std::string.
We are still learning the old C++(I don't know why). Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Yeah. And that's how it is. Can't do anything.

Answer (score -2):

I'm sure your instructor meant:

```
char name[20]="This is a name";
```

or even

```
char name[]="This is a name";
```

Comment: No she didn't. She told me the same thing and I knew that she was wrong. What do you think about this code.

char *name;
name = "vikram";

Comment: That's nearly the same as my suggestion. Except that you have to declare your variable as const char *  .Or else the compiler will complain.
const char* name; name="Vikram";

Comment: Yeah it did complain with a warning. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote but, despite providing an alternative, you didn't actually answer the question by explaining the problem.